# Unregister custom post type from Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm trying to remove a custom post type that was set via a different theme in Wordpress, now all of those posts are assigned to a `post_type` of `portfolio`. After a lot of searching, I found the code below, however it doesn't seem to work. I tried adding it both to the new theme and the old themes `functions.php`.

I want to remove the post_type and have the posts categorized and displayed as a normal post. I think what I'm doing is correct, but can't seem to get it to work - I've posted both the code for the custom post type and the code to unregister the posts assigned to it.

Code to uregister post type

```
if ( ! function_exists( 'unregister_post_type' ) ) :
function unregister_post_type() {
global $wp_post_types;
if ( isset( $wp_post_types[ 'portfolio' ] ) ) {
    unset( $wp_post_types[ 'portfolio' ] );
    return true;
}
return false;
}
endif;

add_action('init', 'unregister_post_type');
```

Code that registered the post type

```
register_post_type( 'portfolio',
    array(
        'labels' => array(
             'name' => __('Portfolio Items'),
             'singular_name' => __('Portfolio Item'),
             'add_new_item' => __('Add New Portfolio Item'),
             'edit_item' => __('Edit Portfolio Item'),
             'new_item' => __('New Portfolio Item'),
             'view_item' => __('View Portfolio Item'),
             'search_items' => __('Search Portfolio Items'),
             'not_found' => __('No portfolio items found'),
             'not_found_in_trash' => __('No portfolio items found in Trash')
        ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'hierarchical' => false,
        'menu_position' => 7,
        //'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'portfolio'),
        'rewrite' => true,
        '_built_in' => false,
        'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag','category','portfolio_tag', 'portfolio_category', 'client'),
        'supports' => array( 'title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions')
    )
);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was able to remove it in WordPress 4.6.1 using this code:

```
function delete_post_type(){
  unregister_post_type( 'portfolio' );
}
add_action('init','delete_post_type', 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code look good! But if you unregister the post_type... the posts in it go away... So don't unregister it too soon. Before you unregister the post type, migrate the posts from the post_type to normal posts. This plugin is handy for that: https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-switcher/

But if you don't want to migrate the video posts to the default posts... You'll have to modify your loop to include those portfolio-type posts:

```
function add_custom_post_type_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array('post', 'portfolio') );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_custom_post_type_to_query' );
```

& don't forget to visit the permalinks page when working with custom post types to get WordPress to recognize the changes you've made.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (with a large priority number)

```
function custom_unregister_theme_post_types() {
    global $wp_post_types;

      if ( isset( $wp_post_types["portfolio"] ) ) {
         unset( $wp_post_types[ "portfolio" ] ); //UPDATED
      }

}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_unregister_theme_post_types', 20 );
```

Note: make sure that the registered post type name is `portfolio` or `portfolios` (with s), register_post_type( ***$post_type***, $args )

**UPDATED:** `unset( $wp_post_types[ "portfolio" ] ); //UPDATED`

Comment: Still not working unfortunately. I added it to functions.php of both the new theme and the old theme that registered the post type.

Comment: It it comes from a different theme, can you please change `init` to `after_setup_theme`? and if from any plugin use `plugins_loaded` hook.

Comment: Also, refer [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3820/deregister-custom-post-types) post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for unregistering custom post types in wordpress. Just remember that you need to clear your functions.php from function that registered your post type in first place.

```
if( !function_exists( 'prefix_unregister_post_type' ) ) {
  function prefix_unregister_post_type() {
    unregister_post_type( 'portfolio' );
  }
}
add_action('init','prefix_unregister_post_type');
```

Answer (score 0):

If the post type refuses to unregister, and if the "register_post_type" function isn't in functions.php, see if the registration is saved in a "must use plugin". As a reminder I place this comment at the top of my functions.php

```
/* if something is stuck, look in must use plugins!!! */
```